# How does SSL protect the data against sniffing?

Tags: java, security, ssl, encryption

I've got a small website and it's security is important to me. I don't have the money to buy an SSL certificate so I thought of making one myself (theoretically with java, although I still don't know how would I then decrypt it on the sever side). The users won't trust it like they trust SSL but it would provide the security I'm looking for.

I read a few articles about SSL and I think I got the math behind it but I didn't understand How does it protect from sniffing. If SSL encrypts the password/info/whatever on the client's computer and than sends it to the server for decryption, what problem would there be for a sniffer to sniff the encoded password and send it to the server?

Comment: You don't 'buy an SSL'. You buy an SSL *certificate.*

Comment: A self signed certificate is fine to avoid sniffing when talking to your server. However, no client is sure they're talking to _your_ server and not someone else with some self signed certificate highjacking the traffic. To explain SSL goes a bit far, look at the [TLS handshake for a start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer#TLS_handshake). The key is _both_ parties have part of a secret.

Comment: Nowadays some SSL certificates are for free. For example: https://letsencrypt.org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I don't have the money to buy an SSL certificate

You can't afford not to. You've already wasted more in time than the certificate will cost you.

> so I thought of making one myself (theoretically with java

Not with the Java JRE alone.

> The users won't trust it like they trust SSL but it would provide the security I'm looking for.

Not if the users don't trust it, it won't.

> If SSL encrypts the password/info/whatever on the client's computer and than sends it to the server for decryption, what problem would there be for a sniffer to sniff the encoded password and send it to the server?

It's considerably more complex than that. The client authenticates the server's identity via PKI and the server's certificate. Client and server then negotiate a symmetric session key using the math you referred to. The key itself is never transmitted. Data is encrypted with this key, and sent along with a message authentication code that shows whether the message is intact. Because of the encryption, the data is private; and because of the way the key is negotiated, SSL also provides invulnerability to replay attacks.

Comment: "Not with the Java JRE alone."    why not?

Comment: Because there is nothing public in the JRE that will generate a new certificate.

Comment: That doesn't change the problem.

Comment: Why not? I can "talk" to the server through the url, no?

Comment: There is still nothing public in the JRE that will generate a certificate.